# How to make a structure extern and define its typedef

Tags: c, extern, structure

I'm trying to implement tree algorithms in C. I have declared a extern struct in a header file that is completely independent (b_tree_ds.h). Now I plan to import the file in all source files that want to use this struct. So I must declare it using extern in header.

Now the problem is thhat I want to define its typedef as well. the compiler gives error of multiple storage classes. How should I do that.

```
typedef extern struct node {
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
    int key;    // contains value
}NODE;
```

The actual problem is as follow, which I still can't fix???
I recently learnt how can we use multiple source files with header files to make code portable and hierarchical. In order to do so, I tired creating my tree program using this principal. Here are my files

b_tree_ds.h - This will contain a *declaration* of datastructure of node of a tree, which can be called to various functions implementing different functionality of the tree (which may be in different source files)

```
typedef struct node {
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
    int key;    // contains value
}NODE;
```

When i try adding a extern as in typedef `extern struct node` it gives a error of multiple storage class but if I miss it, I get error for multiple definitions.

Here are my other source files

traverse.h  - contains declaration of traverse function

```
void traverse_print (NODE* p);
```

Here also I get error for unknown identifier NODE

traverse.c - contains definition to that function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "b_tree_ds.h"
#include "traverse.h"

void traverse_print(NODE* p)
{
    if(p->left != NULL)
    {
        traverse_print(p->left);
    }

    if (p->right != NULL)
    {
        traverse_print(p->right);
    }

    printf ("\n%d",p->key);
}
```

Finally main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "traverse.h"

void main()
{
    // input
    NODE p;

    printf("\nInput the tree");
    input_tree (&p);

    printf("\n\nThe tree is traversing ...\n")
    traverse_print(&p);
}

void input_tree (NODE *p)
{
    int in;
    int c;
    NODE *temp;

    printf("\n Enter the key value for p: ");
    scanf("%d", &in);
    p->key  =in;
    printf ("\n\nIn relation to node with value %d",in);
    printf ("Does it have left child (Y/N): ")
    if ((c = getchar()) == Y);
    {
        //assign new memory to it.
        temp = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        input_tree(temp);
    }
    printf ("\n\nIn relation to node with value %d",p->key);

    printf ("\nDoes it have right child (Y/N): ")
    if ((c = getchar()) == Y);
    {
        //assign new memory to it.
        temp = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        input_tree(temp);
    }
}
```

This is my first attempt to such practice, please suggest is the structuring of my program good or should I try something else.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can't make a struct `extern`. Just define it in an include-guard protected header and include that header everywhere you need it.

#### EDIT for SquareRootOfTwentyThree

I use those therms in [the following way](http://www.msg.ucsf.edu/local/programs/IBM_Compilers/C:C++/html/language/ref/clrc03defst.htm):

> A structure type definition describes the members that are part of the
> structure. It contains the struct keyword followed by an optional
> identifier (the structure tag) and a brace-enclosed list of members.
>
> A structure declaration has the same form as a structure definition
> except the declaration does not have a brace-enclosed list of members.

So "definition" is exactly what I meant.

Comment: In general, definition implies allocation of storage, which should typically not happen in a header (no matter if it is guarded). In headers you do declarations. Your answer is therefore confusing. Please argument with references to the C standards, not to some interpretation found on the web.

Comment: @SquareRootOfTwentyThree I think you're nitpicking. I stand by my answer: in this context "define" is crystal clear, you can't confuse it with anything else.

Comment: It's not clear. You're literally saying that the user should _define_ the struct in the header. Just change it to _declare_ and it's fine..

Comment: cant you extern a struct like how you extern a variable(with slight changes)? Create a header extern.h that contains extern Sruct1 S,Create another header struct.h that contains the typedef struct Sruct1,then finally declare the struct Sruct1 S in any single .c file. Include header extern.h & struct.h in all files that this struct needs to be used. This struct now can be accessed anywhere

Comment: I think of it like this: Declaration specifies identifier. Definition specifies layout. Instantiation implies allocation of storage. There is no storage allocated in a definition. Accepted this as answer.

Answer (score 33):

In C, structures have no linkage, only objects and functions do. So you can write this:

```
// header file 'node.h'

typedef struct node_
{
    /* ... */
} node;

extern node root_node;
```

Then provide an implementation somewhere:

```
// source file

#include <node.h>

node root_node;
```

Comment: *Only objects do* :-? So you include functions there too ?

Comment: @cnicutar: Yeah, I guess I do :-) You can take the address of a function, non?

Comment: Well, there's an issue then, the standard says somewhere: *An identiﬁer can denote an object; a function; a tag or a member of a structure, union, or enumeration; a typedef name; a label name; a macro name; or a macro parameter*. So I can see a distinction between object and function.

Comment: What are objects in C?

Comment: @Pithikos: Things which have storage and which can be values. E.g. an `int`.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for a while. I forgot the name after `struct` ... :(

Comment: If 'object' is your word for things that are linked against, is 'symbol' a more correct word? Is that what you are searching for because C has no concept of objects?

Answer (score 3):

In your header file declare node.h like this

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct node {
        struct node* left;
        struct node* right;
        int key;    // contains value
    }NODE;


#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* NODE_H */
```

you can include this header file in any c program and use it like

```
NODE* newNode = NULL;
```

Comment: This produces an error
error: multiple storage classes in declaration specifiers

Comment: `extern "C" {}` works only if you are using a C++ compiler.

Comment: This specific implementation will still work in C compilers. The `#ifdef __cplusplus` guard guarantees only the C++ compiler will be able to see that part.